# Add label between colorbar breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend

I am trying to create a figure with ggplot and would like to add category names between colorbar breaks (values). I am using a graduated colorbar using the `scale_color_fermenter` function, which I think makes it a bit tricky to do this.

Below is an example code

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=carb, color=disp)) + 
geom_point(size=3)+ 
scale_color_fermenter(breaks = c(100,300,400), palette = "Blues") #graduate colorbar
```

The resulting figure looks like this

[image]

I want to add categories (A, B, C, etc.) between the colorbar breaks (i.e., create categories for `disp`), such that

```
0<=A<100 
100<=B<300 
300<=C<400
400<=D<500
```

The resulting figure looks like this (or similar)

[image]

I know I can add extra breaks and change the label. Something like the following

```
scale_color_fermenter(breaks=c(50,100,200,300,350,400,450,500), 
                      labels=c('A','100','B','300','C','400','D','500'))
```

But this would mess up the colorbar class (i.e., colorbar will have more colors), which is something I do not want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the same approach as by @zephryl but with some additional styling and fiddling and using `ggtext::element_markdown` just in case you want some additional styling for the text labels.

- Using `lineheight` I add some padding between the tick and the category labels.
- Using `vjust` I shift the labels so that the position of the tick labels corresponds approximately to the boundaries of the legend keys.

```r
library("ggplot2")

mylabels <- function(x) {
  paste0(
    c(rep("", length(x) - 1), paste0("<span style='color: red'>", LETTERS[length(x) + 1], "</span><br>")),
    x,
    "<br><span style='color: red'>", LETTERS[seq_along(x)], "</span>"
  )
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = carb, color = disp)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_fermenter(breaks = c(100, 300, 400), labels = mylabels, palette = "Blues") +
  theme(legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(vjust = c(.85, .85, .55), lineheight = 1.25))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = carb, color = disp)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3)+ 
  scale_color_fermenter(
    breaks = c(100,300,400), 
    labels = c("B\n100\nA", "C\n300\n", "D\n400\n"),
    palette = "Blues"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to draw the letters on as annotations:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, carb, color = disp)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  scale_color_fermenter(breaks = c(100, 300, 400)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
           x = 1.02, y = seq(0.39, 0.57, 0.058))) +
  theme(legend.box.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work with `facet_wrap`, `facet_grid`, or if the legend is placed somewhere else.